# ios11 game center find player fails

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, multiplayer, gamekit

I am developing a multi player game. I want to use "standard" GKMatchmakerViewController for finding players like this:

```
let matchrequest = GKMatchRequest()
matchrequest.minPlayers = 2
matchrequest.maxPlayers = 2
matchrequest.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
matchrequest.inviteMessage = "Hello, do you want to play with me ?"

let mmVC = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchrequest)
mmVC?.matchmakerDelegate = self
self.present(mmVC!, animated: true)
```

If I invoke the GKMatchmakerViewController on both devices and press "Play now" they find each other and everything ist fine.

However when I press "Invite Friends", press the "+" on the right to add a recipient and go then to the tab "Nearby" NO players show up.

Q1: Why don't I see the player in "Nearby" but can connect to it by pressing "Play now"

Q2: If I send an invitation to my other player via iMessage the message is received on the other device and when I click it the app gets launched. But it remains at its Main Screen and doesn't take any action to respond to the invitation. What Protocol or Callback needs to be implemented in order to react to app launches caused by "game invitations" ?

Please refer to the latest API. The GC APIs have changed dramatically and most SO answers refer to the deprecated API.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

For Q2. you need to implement GKLocalPlayerListener to answer calls.

How were you able to send invites? I'm trying to figure out how to get a GKPlayer from a string. Like If I want to send an invite to my friend "Blazing420" how do I know his GKPlayer ID or how do I find him, since GKMatchRequest.recipients only takes GKPlayers as arguments.

Comment: I use the GKMatchmakerViewController and when it opens you can press "invite" and then you enter just the appleID. The system the sends a iMessage which you can click on the other device.